# Django dynamic Q date filter gives mysterious results

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to query dynamically in Django with Q objects based on variables as follows:

```
    #...
    if start_date:
        start_time: datetime = get_end_of_time(start_date)
        q_objects = Q(_connector=Q.OR)
        query_filters = [field + '__gte' for field in fields]
        for _filter in query_filters:
            q_objects.add(Q(**{_filter: start_time}), Q.OR)
        things = things.filter(q_objects)

    if end_date:
        end_time: datetime = get_end_of_time(end_date)
        q_objects = Q(_connector=Q.OR)
        query_filters = [field + '__lte' for field in fields]
        for _filter in query_filters:
            q_objects.add(Q(**{_filter: end_time}), Q.OR)
        things = things.filter(q_objects)
```

q_objects looks as follows (end_date condition):

`(OR: ('created_at__lte', datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 6, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'EET' EEST+3:00:00 DST>)), ('started_at__lte', datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 6, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'EET' EEST+3:00:00 DST>)))`

However, it returns `things` that have created_at or started_at after the specified dates:

```
started_at: 2020-07-22 12:45:48.160277+00:00
created_at: 2020-08-07 13:40:48.516932+00:00
```

It works fine if I manually query the objects as follows:

```
things = things.filter(Q(created_at__lte=end_time) | Q(started_at__lte=end_time))
```

So I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong? And more importantly (so I'd learn), why is this happening? What really bugs me is that it *only* returns a few cases outside the specified range, and not all.

Edit:
Here is the output of things.query:

```
("thing"."started_at" >= 2020-08-02 00:00:00+03:00 OR "thing"."created_at" >= 2020-08-02 00:00:00+03:00) AND ("thing"."started_at" <= 2020-08-06 23:59:59.999999+03:00 OR "thing"."created_at" <= 2020-08-06 23:59:59.999999+03:00))
```

Comment: WShat is the `end_time: ` part doing here? the colon (`:`) looks odd.

Comment: It's a type hint (added in python 3.8.6)

Answer (score 0):

My problem obviously was that instead of chaining the dates in the same condition

they were chained as I posted above. Stupid late night issue. So the fix was to build it so that the query ends up looking like
`(created_at => <date> AND created_at <= <date>) OR (started_at => <date> AND started_at <= <date>)`